# Microsoft bot on AWS Lambda (botbuilder-aws-lambda) errors

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, botframework, serverless-framework

I have a developed a Microsoft bot that works using the botframework emulator, I want to host it on AWS Lambda, and am using the following code and when I execute it on lambda, it results in errors.

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const lambda = require('botbuilder-aws-lambda');
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
   appId: 'My App ID',
   appPassword: 'PassWord ID' 
});
exports.handler = lambda(connector); 

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
 });
```

The following are the errors:

```
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 2d91dffa-84d3-11e7-870e-0151204c40e6 Process exited before completing request"
```

The detailed log file shows the following:

```
2017-08-19T11:40:20.889Z    2d91dffa-84d3-11e7-870e-0151204c40e6    SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at handler (/var/task/node_modules/botbuilder-aws-lambda/lib/index.js:5:24)

  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 2d91dffa-84d3-11e7-870e-0151204c40e6 Process exited before completing request"
```

Comment: Botbuilder-aws-lambda's code is quite simple. For some reason you are not receiving a JSON in the `event.body`. See
https://github.com/palmerabollo/botbuilder-aws-lambda/blob/master/lib/index.js#L7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is, but I thought I would share some of my  learning working with Twilio and AWS Lambda.  Not sure if this is what you already know or not however:

1. API Gateway - in order to expose an HTTP endpoint via a Lambda, you require a API Gateway configured to point to the AWS Lambda.
2. Lambda Request - the only payload that Lambda will receive is a JSON payload.  Twilio will only produce a FORM-URL-Encoded format.  You have to configure API Gateway to transform the Form-URL-Endcoded to JSON.
3. Lambda Reply - JSON in, JSON out.  To convert the reply from JSON to TwiXML, you have to transform the message from JSON to TwilXML

AWS Lambda, IMO, doesn't hold a candle to Azure Functions.  Do yourself a favour and try Azure Functions - it does not have any the restrictions of AWS Lambda, and does not have to go through a translation layer like API Gateway. In addition, and likely the best feature, you can run it locally without having to create your own framework. Why AWS would not prioritize a local development environment is beyond me - other than perhaps being first to market.

HTH